# SoapUI wsdl wcf net.tcp missing importer

Tags: wcf, wsdl, soapui, wcf-data-services, wcftestclient

Nn generall I have serving hosting on tcp and I can't parse my wsdl with SoapUI, while it works with wcfTestClient.

SoapUI gives me error:
Missing importer for...
Missing portType for binding..

Unfortunally I need to add headers which I heard is immposible for wcfTestClient.

[image]

And my service configuration

```
<service name=".." behaviorConfiguration="...">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://.." bindingConfiguration="SecureNetTcpBinding" contract="..." address="" />
        <endpoint address="mex" bindingNamespace="http://.." binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureNetTcpBindingMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:50002...svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

        <binding name="SecureNetTcpBindingMex" maxConnections="400" listenBacklog="400">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Is it possible to parse wcf net.tcp with SoapUI ? If not what options do I have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="...">
    <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Then consume into SoapUI from http://localhost:50002...svc/soap